# Postgres returning empty result if one of the outcome is null

Tags: postgresql

Postgres returning empty result if one of the outcome is null.

For a scenario, consider a table,

table: books

```
  id  |   title   |  is_free  |
  1   |     A     |    true   |
  2   |     B     |    false  |
```

```
select 'some_text' as col, b.title
from (select title from books
      where id = 3) as b;
```

In this case, the number of rows returned is 0.

```
  col    |  title  |
(0 rows)
```

How to return Null as return value?

```
   col     | title   |
 some_text |  NULL   |
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery in a different way:

```
select 'some_text' as col,
       (select title from books where id = 3);
```

Comment: If I am supposed to make a sqlalchemy query in this format. How can I do it? using sqlalchemy core

Comment: No idea. Doesn't SQLAlchemy allow you to run SQL statements?

Comment: Yes. but I am implemening it using sqlalchemy core functions. like `sa.select([...])`